# Java - Using Recursion to Find Palindrome

Tags: java

I am designing a util class that takes a string as a parameter and returns true if it is a palindrome(ex: input: radar ---> output: true) and returns false if it is not. For this class, I am using a linkedlist, however I don't know why there seems to be an error. Here is the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 4
    at java.util.LinkedList.checkElementIndex(LinkedList.java:555)
    at java.util.LinkedList.remove(LinkedList.java:525)
    at com.run.FindPalindromes.FindMain(FindPalindromes.java:20)
    at com.run.FindPalindromes.FindMain(FindPalindromes.java:16)
    at com.run.Test.main(Test.java:7)
```

And Here is the source code:

```
public boolean FindMain(String in){
    if(times == 0){
    search = new LinkedList(cc.convertStringToArraylist(in)); 
    times ++;
    FindMain(null);
    } else {
        if(search.get(search.size()-1).equals(search.get(0))){
            search.remove(0);
            search.remove(search.size());
            FindMain(null);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not Palindrome");
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

`search.remove(search.size())` should be `search.remove(search.size() - 1)` since lists are zero-based. If you have four elements your list indices run from 0 to 3, and so there is nothing at location 4.

Also your code as it stands won't handle empty lists very well, so that's something you need to check.